Decarboxylation of malonic esters
It is common in alpha carbon chemistry that malonic ester is used for organic synthesis, the decarboxylation in acidic medium should give the carboxylic acid. However, it is not mentioned for the two below esters, whether they are capable of undergoing the same reaction

Is it possible that two reaction occur?

I dont find issues with the transition states, they are geminal dicarboxylic acids and decarboxylation should occur. Both should show $A_{AC}^1$ hydrolysis

Both reactions are possible. Both occur by first loosing the two terminal ethyl groups (hydrolysis), then decarboxylation of one of the acidic groupe -COOH

So, the intermediate of the second reaction must be allene, is it not?

While monoalkylated malonic esters hydrolyze and decarboxylate in refluxing aq. acid, the dialkylated malonic acids, in my experience, require them to be heated neat at elevated temperatures for a short time. Methylidene malonic acid readily polymerizes without decarboxylation.

@user55119 please share any source you find, for the same

References for Cuckoo Beats: Dialkyl malonic acid and methylidene malonic acid.

The three types of decarboxylations I have seen thus far are $\beta-$keto carboxylic acid$^1$; $\beta,\gamma-$unsaturated carboxylic acid$^2$ (although some instances of $\alpha,\beta-$unsaturated decarboxylation are there, discussed in the same page) and geminal dicarboxlyic acid.
Yours is the example of the geminal malonic acid decarboxylation, you can also find more information at Master Organic Chemistry$^3$ while it discusses malonic ester synthesis at length, for instance, here is an excerpt from the same

Now comes the part which often gives students trouble. When carboxylic acids have a carbonyl group (C=O) two bonds away, they can readily lose carbon dioxide. Why? Because the carbonyl can act as an electron “sink” for the pair of electrons coming from the breaking C–C bond, forming an enol. This is called “decarboxylation”. Note how this is also the case for carboxylic acids with a ketone two bonds away, so-called “β-keto acids”. [See article – Decarboxylation$^1$]

The above excerpt is an example of monoalkylated malonic acid. The decarboxylation proceeds through a 6 membered cyclic transition state,  which also suggests why any other dicarboxylic acid doesn't undergo decarboxylation.
Now @user55119 said something about acid reflux, refluxing in aqueous acid provides the necessary thermal energy to overcome the activation energy barrier for both hydrolysis and decarboxylation. Additionally, the aqueous environment stabilizes ionic intermediates, enhancing the reaction.
Following is more information about synthesizing malonic acid in this patent$^4$

Malonic acid is prepared according to the invention by heating an aqueous mixture of a malonic acid di-ester; a hydrolysis catalyst, and malonic acid and/or a malonic acid mono-ester to a temperature suficient for fairly rapid hydrolysis of the di-ester, but below that at which malonic acid itself is appreciably decomposed. Although any di-ester of malonic acid may be used as a starting material, di-alkyl malonates, particularly those containing less than $4$ carbon atoms in each alkyl radical are usually employed, and diethyl malonate is preferred. Examples of other di-esters which may be used as starting materials are dimethyl malonate, dipropyl malonate, di-
isopropyl malonate, dibutyl malonate, diphenyl malonate, ditolyl malonate, dibenzyl malonate, etc.


Moving on to dialkylated malonic esters, we face yet another challenge. Here is my version of the mechanism, as charge separations are unfavourable, the actual mechanism is concerted
 
You would have noticed right away that the negative charge on the $\beta-$carbon is highly unstable. Also there are steric factors due to which the planar intermediate is difficult to obtain 
Here are some more lines from the same patent$^4$

In a method wherein malonic acid is prepared by hydrolyzing a malonic acid dialkyl ester in the presence of an acid-acting hydrolysis catalyst, the steps of initially adding to the reaction mixture an agent selected from the class consisting of malonic acid and lower mono-alkyl esters of malonic acid in amount corresponding to between $0.2$ and $0.5$ of a molecular equivalent of the dialkyl malonate, heating the reaction mixture to a reaction temperature below $\pu{100^\circ C}$, in such manner as to distill alcohol from the mixture-as it is formed, continuing heating of the mixture at below $\pu{100^\circ C}$, and at subatmospheric pressure to evaporate water therefrom and concentrate the malonic acid product and thereafter crystallizing the malonic acid from the mixture and separating the crystalline product.
A cyclic method for the preparation of malonic acid by the hydrolysis of diethyl malonate which comprises heating an aqueous mixture of diethyl malonate, sulphuric acid and added malonic acid to a reaction temperature between $50$ and $\pu{70^\circ C}$ at sub-atmospheric pressure in such manner as to distill from the mixture, ethyl alcohol formed by the hydrolysis, thereafter evaporating water from the mixture by continuing heating of the latter at a temperature below $\pu{70^\circ C}$ and at sub-atmospheric pressure until the residual mixture contains between $70$ and about $90$ per cent of malonic acid, cooling the mixture to crystallize malonic acid therefrom, removing the crystalline product, and admixing the mother liquor, which contains the sulphuric acid and dissolved malonic acid, with further amounts of water and diethyl malonate and hydrolyzing the latter by heating the resultant mixture under the reaction conditions above specified.


@user55119 mentioned yet another fact- to decarboxylate, dialkylated malonic acids are typically heated neat (without solvent) at elevated temperatures (e.g., $\pu{>150^\circ C}$). High temperatures provide the energy needed to overcome the steric and electronic barriers. This ACS journal article$^5$ likely discusses experimental conditions where dialkyl malonic acids decarboxylate under thermal conditions. I am unable to access the patent, so I cannot reference anything from there.

Now moving on to methylene malonic acid, here is my version of the mechanism, yet again, the actual one is concerted 
@user55119 had mentioned a unique point, the exocyclic double bond introduces significant reactivity, making the molecule prone to polymerization. The double bond is highly electrophilic due to the electron-withdrawing carboxylic acid groups. Under heat or in the presence of other nucleophiles, the double bond reacts to form a polymer chain rather than decarboxylating. This cited patent$^6$ claims so. Also, this patent$^7$ discusses this exact issue at length although it is the reverse process, to synthesize the ester. For instance, here are some lines from the same patent$^7$

However, earlier methods for producing methylene malonates suffer significant deficiencies that preclude their use in obtaining commercially viable monomers. Such deficiencies include unwanted polymerization of the monomers during synthesis, formation of undesirable side products, degradation of the product, insufficient and/or low yields, and ineffective and/or poorly functioning monomer product. These problems have impinged on their practical use in the production of commercial and industrial products.


Links/References

Decarboxylation By James Ashenhurst -
https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2022/05/20/decarboxylation/ 
Chemistry Stackexchange - How do α,β-unsaturated acids undergo decarboxylation?
The Malonic Ester and Acetoacetic Ester synthesis By James Ashenhurst - https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2012/08/14/the-malonic-ester-synthesis/
Edgar C. Britton and Ezra Monroe, "Production of Malonic acid" U.S. Patent - 2,373,011 - https://patents.google.com/patent/US2373011A/en
Frederick E. Ziegler, Irene Chliwner, Kerry W. Fowler, Sheldon J. Kanfer, Stephen J. Kuo, Nanda D. Sinha, "The ambient temperature Ullmann reaction and its application to the total synthesis of (.+-.)-steganacin" - https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja00522a058#
WANG JUNPING; GUO YIN, "Poly(2-carboxyl acrylic acid), and preparation method and application thereof", Chinese Patent
CN110498877A; CN110498877B; CN115353578A - https://worldwide.espacenet.com/patent/search/family/068591404/publication/CN110498877A?q=CN110498877A
Bernard M. Malofsky; Adam G. Malofsky; Matthew M. Ellison; Stanley C. Wojciak, "METHODS FOR ACTIVATING POLYMERIZABLE COMPOSITIONS, POLYMERIZABLE SYSTEMS, AND PRODUCTS FORMED THEREBY"- U.S. Patent 9,181,365 B2, Nov. 10, 2015- https://portal.unifiedpatents.com/patents/patent/US-9181365-B2


hello, this is my first answer at chemistry SE, corrections are welcomed

See my Comment above.
